# add Decoration Overlay in device settings in Android 11

Tags: android, kotlin, permissions, sdk

I have a button to go back to my default app in my Android device, overlaying the system screens.

But I cant overlay the device settings in this version of Android 11, for example in Android 10 I had no problem. In some screens the arrow is visible but when I open the settings it disapears.

It is something related to permissions in Android 11? thanks.

I tried the permission MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, but did not work for me